# Facebook like button expands downwards through no-overflow page

Tags: button, popup, facebook-like

Is there any way to make the like button expand upwards instead of downwards, as on my page http://frc1410.org the like button is placed in a footer, and I would love to have it either expand upwards, or push the entire footer up so it is visible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit the CSS for the class pluginCommentFlyoutFull. The top property for that class could be set to a negative value. You will also need to do that for other HTML elements in the like button fly out. You also will need to do some z-index to have it appear over your main content wrapper.

> .pluginCommentFlyoutFull { width: 450px; top: -157px; }

Comment: Where can I find that CSS? I'm using Facebook's "simple" like button creator, so I don't actually host the CSS. I use this to call the CSS and javascript.                                                                             `</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>`

Comment: I see. Try overwriting it by putting the pluginCommentFlyoutFull class in your own style sheet and see if that works. Try something like **.fbpf.pluginCommentFlyout.pluginCommentFlyoutFull {width: 450px; top: -157px;}** in your style sheet.

Comment: Nope.... added it to my style sheet and it didn't work. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: the precedence for loading style is element level, document level then external. if external fails, can you try on document level? i mean on the same html document header add **<style>.pluginCommentFlyoutFull { width: 450px; top: -157px; }</style>**

Comment: That seemed to work, but the style is flawed, I'll check out some more styles in the mean time. Thinks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer works only for the comment. Little bit more difficult for the Like dialog.

For me, the others no-go where the time of loading that was blocking the page, and the smurf due to change size.

We killed 4 birds with one stone with the following solution:
- The Facebook Like dialog appears above the like botton and at the top z-index level
- it's fully asynchronous, thus non blocking for the page,
- we automatically create the right url entry so the same javascript is used in all our pages,
- and it updates and shows it only after the actual size is known

Picture after click on like:
http://www.plixo.com.sg/download/fb_open_up.png

So here is how we do it:

1) we include in all our pages an "empty" div that is than filled in javascript:
`<div id="social-media-bar"><div id="social-media"></div></div>`

PS: the reason for 2 levels of div is because I will later extend this to google+, twitter etc

2) we load facebook asynchronously
using LazyLoad loader but any will do and you can also do synchronous if you want:
`LazyLoad.js(('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +

'connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js');`

3) in the facebook init, we:
- fill the dedicated div,
- ask fb to parse the inserted tags
- use a timeout after parsing to ensure display has been refreshed and thus widht and height are correct.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
        var d = document,n,nn,url,url_ref,i;`

        // due to bug in facebook need to delay the actual access to data after parse
        function FBUpdateSize(){
            var h,str;
            // show facebook entry using actual element size
            h = nn.firstChild.clientHeight;
            str = h+'px';
            nn.style.height= str;
            n.style.height= str;
            n.style.overflow='visible';
        }

        FB.init({   channelUrl : 'http://www.plixo.com.sg/channel.html',
                    //appId : '228760567272221', 
                    status     : false,
                    xfbml      : false}); 

        // create facebook entries in the DOM
        n = d.getElementById('social-media');
        url = d.URL;
        i = url.lastIndexOf('/')+1;
        url_ref = url.slice(i,url.indexOf('.',i));
        nn = d.createElement('fb-like');
        nn.innerHTML = '<div id="fb_like_bottom"><fb:like href="' + url + '" ref="' + url_ref + '" send="false" layout="standard" width="360px" show_faces="false"></fb:like></div>';
        nn = n.appendChild(nn);

        // call facebook to fill DOM entries
        // use a timeout in callback to ensure browser has refreshed internal clientHeight
        FB.XFBML.parse(nn,function(){setTimeout(FBUpdateSize,50)});
    };`
```

4) and only 3 dedicated css styles:
`#social-media{position:relative;display:block;width:auto;z-index:200;overflow:hidden;height:0;

background-color:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #bdc7d8}`
`#fb_like_bottom{padding:4px;position:absolute}`
`#fb_like_bottom .fb_iframe_widget_lift{bottom:0;background-color:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #bdc7d8

!important;margin:-5px;padding:4px}`

You can look at an example in any of our website pages, ex, http://www.plixo.com.sg/pipe-markers.html

Feel free to reuse/modify etc, will just appreciate if you link to any of our page ;-)